# "List of devices attached" is empty on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

I am unable connect my Android to Ubuntu. I have added rule to `udev`, I have added device to `adb_usb.ini` and I'm still getting same empty list.

My lsusb:

```
`Bus 002 Device 124: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II]`
```

adb_usb.ini

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE. 
0x0e79
0x04e8
```

51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666"
```

And I have usb debugging on. Is there anything else that I can try?

**EDIT**

I have tried to restart adb-server with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, but it also doesn't help me.

Comment: `adb kill-server` then `adb devices` -- phone has USB Debugging enabled, right?

Comment: `adb kill-server` then `sudo adb start-server`

Comment: A few readers might find useful to be reminded that USB debugging has to be enable, and [how to enable developper tools](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/73438) when they're not (at least on CyanogenMod).  It was all I was missing when coming here…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem is caused by my smartphone. I tried to plug in Android 4.3 and it works correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a lot of advices to be my Android device visible by "adb devices" command but none worked.
And finally I found.
Just add your Android device vendor ID (like 0x1f3a) to

**~/.android/adb_usb.ini**

and then try other advices.

Comment: Not useful if you don't explain how to get the vendor ID (`lsusb` in Linux), or the file format in case it does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that I did not have the necessary phone drivers

For **LG G3** (maybe others)

1. We had to go to the USB options when connecting
2. Allow installation of applications from the phone
3. Waiting for installation
4. Select the PTP (Send images mode)

Comment: Thank you, what was missing was installing the LG PC Suite and that is triggered from phone options as you said.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are having intermittent problems with adb. Here's a simple procedure you can use to rectify the issue.

Keep the device connected.

run

```
sudo adb kill-server
```

then go into your mobile device and

revoke all usb authorizations in your android developer section in settings on your mobile device.

Next turn debugging off and then on again after 10 secs or so.
You will get a pop up for authorization in your device.

Select yes to it on the device and then run the following in terminal

```
 sudo adb devices -l
```

Your device should be back in action.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding device in android rules file:

#### Use the following commands in Ubuntu:

How to get the device vendor id:

```
lsusb
```

Command for adding device rules, run the following commands:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case After
`adb kill-server`
I did 
`sudo adb start-server`
then 
`sudo adb devices`
and got it worked!